# How can I manage separate app.yaml / cron.yaml for my app engine source code?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-analytics

I have two versions of my app, prod and dev that I manage from one git repo.  The way I've been managing them is to constantly switch and uncomment lines in both my app.yaml and my cron.yaml depending upon which version I want to upload.

I was wondering if anyone had better experience managing two different versions within one git repo.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using two branches where the app.yaml files are different.  But it requires that I have to be careful when merging and explicitly NOT merge the app.yaml file.  It's still a pain.

Comment: Thanks dragonx, that was my mistake recently, forgot to switch the cron targets so I was hitting the default version with my dev cron jobs.  I'll research how to merge my dev changes up but ignoring those two files, cron.yaml and app.yaml.

Comment: I think the solution is to branch a dev version off production and use set the attribute to "ours" in the prod branch for cron.yaml and app.yaml

Comment: Thanks!  I've been doing this manually, but that looks like it'll make it more automated and less error prone!